# using two scale colour gradients on one ggplot

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, scale, gradient

I would like to combine a colour scale gradient for the points on a scatter plot together with a colour scale gradient for some text that goes on the plot. I can do them separately as shown in my example below, but i can't seem to put them together...is there a way of doing this?

Here is my example code of the two types of plots (p and p1) that I want to combine

```
l <- data.frame(prev=rnorm(1266), 
            aft=rnorm(1266), 
            day=as.factor(wday(sample(c(2:6),1266,replace=TRUE),abbr=TRUE, label=TRUE)), 
            month=as.factor(month(Sys.Date()+months(sample(0:11,1266,replace=TRUE)),abbr=TRUE, label=TRUE)), 
            ind=c(1:1266))
cors <- ddply(l, c("month", "day"), summarise, cor = round(cor(prev, aft), 3))


# below the text gains the colour gradient
p <- ggplot(l, aes(x=prev, y=aft)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    scale_colour_gradient(low = "red", high="blue")+ 
    facet_grid(day~month, scales="free_x")+
    geom_text(data=cors,aes(label=paste("r= ",cor,sep=""), size=abs(cor), colour=cor), x=Inf, y=Inf, vjust=1, hjust=1, show_guide=FALSE)+
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0))+
    geom_smooth(method="loess")
p

# below the points gain the colour gradient
p1 <- ggplot(l, aes(x=prev, y=aft)) + 
    geom_point(aes(colour=ind)) + 
    scale_colour_gradient("gray")+ 
    facet_grid(day~month, scales="free_x")+
    geom_text(data=cors,aes(label=paste("r= ",cor,sep=""), size=abs(cor), colour=cor), x=Inf, y=Inf, vjust=1, hjust=1, show_guide=FALSE)+
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0))+
    opts(legend.position="none") +
    geom_smooth(method="loess")

p1
```

Comment: FYI Some folks will find it somewhat irritating that you've cross posted this on the ggplot2 mailing list as well. It's fine to seek help in multiple places, but please try to ask in one place first, and only move to another forum if you haven't gotten an answer after some reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not expect that this can be done. A plot only has one scale per aesthetic. I believe that if you add multiple `scale_color`'s, the second will overwrite the first. I think Hadley created this behavior on purpose, within a plot the mapping from data to a scale in the plot, e.g. color, is unique. This ensures that all color in the plot can be compared easily, because they share the same `scale_color`.

Comment: Hmm, interesting and thanks for the comment, but if the colour scales are completely different, then surely each can represent something different, especially if one is related to the colour of the text..., while the other relates to the colour of the points

Comment: @h.l.m Just so you know, Hadley's "official" position seems to be that he's not 100% opposed to the _idea_ of multiple scales, but implementing it in a way that works seamlessly with everything else would be enormously complicated, for a feature with a limited number of uses.

Comment: Why not use scale_alpha to get shades of black ie greys.