# How to create base R plot 'type = b' equivalent in ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Base `plot()` functionality allows one to set `type='b'` and get a combined line and point plot in which the points are offset from the line segments

```
plot(pressure, type = 'b', pch = 19)
```

[image]

I can easily create a ggplot with lines and points as follows.

```
ggplot(pressure, aes(temperature, pressure)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

The lines, however, run right up to the points. I can envision a way that I might hack together something like `type='b'` functionality using other geoms (e.g. `geom_segment()`?), but I am wondering if there is a more direct way to accomplish this with `geom_line()` and `geom_point()`.

Comment: If the trick of using dots of different sizes on top of each other is not good enough you can use `geom_segment` to draw these segments one by one. You need one param for the invisible length, and call our old friend pythagoras to compute `x1` `y1` `x2`, `y2` when relevant (when segment is long enough). That's more complex than current chosen solution but less than the `ggproto` stuff.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper sounds interesting - you still have 24 hours for putting this as an answer for the bounty ;)

Comment: I don't think I'll have time unfortunately, I'll leave it to another bounty hunter this time, if they want it :).

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I have worked on a geom_segment approach using trigonometry ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55853359/7941188)). This works only with `coord_equal` though - therefore my question. Maybe you have an answer :)

Comment: great! l think @teunbrand's kickass answer addresses everything, good job to both of you!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A slightly hacky way of doing this is to overplot a small black point on a larger white point:

```
ggplot(pressure, aes(temperature, pressure)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size=5, colour="white") + 
  geom_point(size=2) + 
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black"))
```

In addition, following [Control point border thickness in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361768/6455166), in version 2.0.0 of `ggplot2` it's possible to use the `stroke` argument of `geom_point` to control the border thickness, so the two `geom_point`s can be replaced by just (e.g.) `geom_point(size=2, shape=21, fill="black", colour="white", stroke=3)`, eliminating the need to overlay the points.

[image]

Answer (score 17):

One option which is less hacky than manually matching the stroke color with the panel background is to get the panel background beforehand, either from `theme_get` for the default theme, or with a specific theme that you'll be using. Using a stroked shape like `21` lets you make the inner circle black and the stroke the same color as the background.

```r
library(ggplot2)

bgnd <- theme_get()$panel.background$fill

ggplot(pressure, aes(x = temperature, y = pressure)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point(shape = 21, fill = "black", size = 2, stroke = 1, color = bgnd)
```

[image]

A couple SO questions ([here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35904363/5325862)) deal with the math behind shortening segments between points. It's simple but tedious geometry. But in the time since this question was first posted, the [`lemon` package](https://github.com/stefanedwards/lemon) has come out, which has a geom to do this. It's got arguments for how to calculate the shortening, which probably require just some simple tweaking.

```r
library(lemon)

ggplot(pressure, aes(x = temperature, y = pressure)) +
  geom_pointline()
```

[image]

Comment: I had hoped that some ggplot big shots as you would answer to the bounty :) The idea of getting the theme background is great. geom_pointline looks interesting - although on my phone the lines look weirdly offset to the points, which is not quite great. I am on the way but will download the package later and play around. Thanks already for pointing this out.

Comment: Just realised (also due to @teunbrand 's answer) that this solution does not (immediately) work when your theme is set to `panel.background = element_blank()`

Comment: That's true, although it seems like most or all of the themes that ship with `ggplot2` have a background fill, even if it's just white

Answer (score 8):

Ok I have an implementation of a geom, that does not rely on hardcoding and should not have wierd offsets. It's essentialy a `geom_point()` implementation, that draws a path* between points, draws a larger background point with colours set to the panel background and then the normal points.

*note that path's behaviour is not to connect points along the x-axis, but along row-order in the `data.frame` that is given to ggplot. You can sort your data beforehand if you want `geom_line()` behaviour.

The main problem for me was to get the inner workings of the geom drawing code to retrieve the theme of the current plot to extract the background colour of the panel. Due to this, I'm very unsure how stable this would be (and would welcome any tips), but at least it works.

EDIT: should be more stable now

Let's get to the, admittedly lengthy, `ggproto` object code:

```
GeomPointPath <- ggproto(
  "GeomPointPath", GeomPoint,
  draw_panel = function(self, data, panel_params, coord, na.rm = FALSE)
  {

    # bgcol <- sys.frame(4)$theme$panel.background$fill
    # if (is.null(bgcol)) {
    #   bgcol <- theme_get()$panel.background$fill
    # }

    # EDIT: More robust bgcol finding -----------
    # Find theme, approach as in https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3116
    theme <- NULL
    for(i in 1:20) {
      env <- parent.frame(i)
      if("theme" %in% names(env)) {
        theme <- env$theme
        break
      }
    }
    if (is.null(theme)) {
      theme <- theme_get()
    }

    # Lookup likely background fills
    bgcol <- theme$panel.background$fill
    if (is.null(bgcol)) {
      bgcol <- theme$plot.background$fill
    }
    if (is.null(bgcol)) {
      bgcol <- theme$rect$fill
    }
    if (is.null(bgcol)) {
      # Default to white if no fill can be found
      bgcol <- "white"
    }
    # END EDIT ------------------

    if (is.character(data$shape)) {
      data$shape <- ggplot2:::translate_shape_string(data$shape)
    }

    coords <- coord$transform(data, panel_params)

    # Draw background points
    bgpoints <- grid::pointsGrob(
      coords$x, coords$y, pch = coords$shape,
      gp = grid::gpar(
        col = alpha(bgcol, NA), 
        fill = alpha(bgcol, NA),
        fontsize = (coords$size * .pt + coords$stroke * .stroke/2) * coords$mult,
        lwd = coords$stroke * .stroke/2
      )
    )

    # Draw actual points
    mypoints <- grid::pointsGrob(
      coords$x, coords$y, pch = coords$shape, 
      gp = grid::gpar(
        col = alpha(coords$colour, coords$alpha), 
        fill = alpha(coords$fill, coords$alpha), 
        fontsize = coords$size * .pt + coords$stroke * .stroke/2, 
        lwd = coords$stroke * .stroke/2
      )
    )

    # Draw line
    myline <- grid::polylineGrob(
      coords$x, coords$y, 
      id = match(coords$group, unique(coords$group)),
      default.units = "native",
      gp = grid::gpar(
        col = alpha(coords$colour, coords$alpha),
        fill = alpha(coords$colour, coords$alpha),
        lwd = (coords$linesize * .pt),
        lty = coords$linetype,
        lineend = "butt",
        linejoin = "round", linemitre = 10
      )
    )

    # Place graphical objects in a tree
    ggplot2:::ggname(
      "geom_pointpath",
      grid::grobTree(myline, bgpoints, mypoints) 
    )
  },
  # Set some defaults, assures that aesthetic mappings can be made
  default_aes = aes(
    shape = 19, colour = "black", size = 1.5, fill = NA, alpha = NA, stroke = 0.5,
    linesize = 0.5, linetype = 1, mult = 3,
  )
)
```

Observant people may have noticed the line `bgcol <- sys.frame(4)$theme$panel.background$fill`. I could not find another way to access the current plot's theme, without having to adjust at least several other functions to pass the theme as an argument. In my version of ggplot (3.1.0), the 4th `sys.frame()` is the environment of the `ggplot2:::ggplot_gtable.ggplot_built` call wherein the geom drawing code is evaluated. It's quite easy to imagine that this function can be updated in the future -which can change the scoping- hence the stability warning. As a backup, it defaults to the global theme settings when it can't find the current theme.

EDIT: should now be more stable

Onwards to the layer wrapper which is pretty much self-explanatory:

```
geom_pointpath <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity",
                           position = "identity", ..., na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA,
                           inherit.aes = TRUE)
{
  layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomPointPath,
        position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
        params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...))
}
```

Adding it to a ggplot should be a familiar thing. Just setting the theme to the default `theme_gray()` to test that it indeed takes the current plot's theme.

```
theme_set(theme_gray())
g <- ggplot(pressure, aes(temperature, pressure)) +
  geom_pointpath() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "dodgerblue"))
```

Of course, this method will obscure grid lines with the background points, but that is the tradeoff I was willing to make to prevent wonkyness due to line path shortening. Line sizes, line types, and the relative size of the background points can be set with `aes(linesize = ..., linetype = ..., mult = ...)` or per the `...` argument in `geom_pointpath()`. It inherits the other aesthetics from `GeomPoint`.

[image]

Comment: thanks, much appreciated. This, as well as @Camille's solution, fails when the theme is set to `panel.background = element_blank()`

Comment: I'll go see if I can find a fix for this

Comment: I guess the (obvious?) reason is, that if the background is “NULL”, there will be nothing to cover the underlying graphs. I guess @Camille is right, when they suggested that in the end every plot comes with a color. however it might become problematic when one wants to explicitly create “transparent” graphs.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. It now looks up values from the inheritance tree of the panel background.  The only reasonable alternative is to use the shortened paths, which I would suspect behave wierdly under extreme aspect ratios. I also tried clipping masks, such as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715907/how-to-apply-a-clipping-mask-to-geom-in-a-ggplot. Problem was that I couldn't get this to work inside the geom drawing code.

Answer (score 7):

I'm sorry for answering twice, but this seems sufficiently different to merit a different answer.

I've given this question some more thought and I'll concede that a geometric approach is indeed the better approach over the point-over-point approach. However, the geometric approach comes with its own set of problems, namely that any attempt at pre-computing coordinates before draw-time is going to give you some skew in one way or another (see [a follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55853359/plot-type-b-in-ggplot-with-geom-segment-adjusting-parameters-to-axis-ratio) from @Tjebo).

It is next to impossible to know the aspect ratio or exact sizes of the plot a priori, except by setting an aspect ratio manually or using the `space` argument of `facet_grid()`. Because this is impossible, any precomputed set of coordinates is going to be inadequate if the plot is resized.

I've shamelessly stolen some good ideas from other people, so thanks to @Tjebo and @moody_mudskipper for the maths and credit to ggplot guru [thomasp85](https://github.com/thomasp85) and the ggforce package for the calculating at drawtime inspiration.

On with it; first we'll define our ggproto as before, now making a custom grob class for our path. An important detail is that we convert our xy coordinates to formal units.

```
GeomPointPath <- ggproto(
  "GeomPointPath", GeomPoint,
  draw_panel = function(data, panel_params, coord, na.rm = FALSE){

    # Default geom point behaviour
    if (is.character(data$shape)) {
      data$shape <- translate_shape_string(data$shape)
    }
    coords <- coord$transform(data, panel_params)
    my_points <- pointsGrob(
      coords$x, 
      coords$y, 
      pch = coords$shape, 
      gp = gpar(col = alpha(coords$colour, coords$alpha), 
                fill = alpha(coords$fill, coords$alpha), 
                fontsize = coords$size * .pt + coords$stroke * .stroke/2, 
                lwd = coords$stroke * .stroke/2))

    # New behaviour
    ## Convert x and y to units
    x <- unit(coords$x, "npc")
    y <- unit(coords$y, "npc")

    ## Make custom grob class
    my_path <- grob(
      x = x,
      y = y,
      mult = (coords$size * .pt + coords$stroke * .stroke/2) * coords$mult,
      name = "pointpath",
      gp = grid::gpar(
        col = alpha(coords$colour, coords$alpha),
        fill = alpha(coords$colour, coords$alpha),
        lwd = (coords$linesize * .pt),
        lty = coords$linetype,
        lineend = "butt",
        linejoin = "round", linemitre = 10
      ),
      vp = NULL,
      ### Now this is the important bit:
      cl = 'pointpath'
    )

    ## Combine grobs
    ggplot2:::ggname(
      "geom_pointpath",
      grid::grobTree(my_path, my_points) 
    )
  },
  # Adding some defaults for lines and mult
  default_aes = aes(
    shape = 19, colour = "black", size = 1.5, fill = NA, alpha = NA, stroke = 0.5,
    linesize = 0.5, linetype = 1, mult = 0.5,
  )
)
```

Through the magic of object oriented programming, we can now write a new method for our new grob class. While that may be uninteresting in and of itself, it gets particularly interesting if we write this method for `makeContent`, which is called every time a grob is drawn. So, let's write a method that invokes the mathematical operations on the exact coordinates the graphics device is going to use:

```
# Make hook for drawing
makeContent.pointpath <- function(x){
  # Convert npcs to absolute units
  x_new <- convertX(x$x, "mm", TRUE)
  y_new <- convertY(x$y, "mm", TRUE)

  # Do trigonometry stuff
  hyp <- sqrt(diff(x_new)^2 + diff(y_new)^2)
  sin_plot <- diff(y_new) / hyp 
  cos_plot <- diff(x_new) / hyp

  diff_x0_seg <- head(x$mult, -1) * cos_plot
  diff_x1_seg <- (hyp - head(x$mult, -1)) * cos_plot
  diff_y0_seg <- head(x$mult, -1) * sin_plot
  diff_y1_seg <- (hyp - head(x$mult, -1)) * sin_plot

  x0 = head(x_new, -1) + diff_x0_seg
  x1 = head(x_new, -1) + diff_x1_seg
  y0 = head(y_new, -1) + diff_y0_seg
  y1 = head(y_new, -1) + diff_y1_seg
  keep <- unclass(x0) < unclass(x1)

  # Remove old xy coordinates
  x$x <- NULL
  x$y <- NULL

  # Supply new xy coordinates
  x$x0 <- unit(x0, "mm")[keep]
  x$x1 <- unit(x1, "mm")[keep]
  x$y0 <- unit(y0, "mm")[keep]
  x$y1 <- unit(y1, "mm")[keep]

  # Set to segments class
  class(x)[1] <- 'segments'
  x
}
```

Now all we need is a layer wrapper like before, which does nothing special:

```
geom_pointpath <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity",
                           position = "identity", ..., na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA,
                           inherit.aes = TRUE)
{
  layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomPointPath,
        position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
        params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...))
}
```

The demonstration:

```
g <- ggplot(pressure, aes(temperature, pressure)) +
  # Ribbon for showing no point-over-point background artefacts
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = pressure - 50, ymax = pressure + 50), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_pointpath()
```

[image]

And this should be stable for any resized aspect ratio. You can supply `aes(mult = ...)` or just `mult = ...` to control the size of the gaps between segments. By default it is proportional to the point sizes, so varying the point size while keeping the gap contant is a challenge. Segments that are shorter than two times the gap are deleted.

Comment: That is totally awesome. Thanks for this. Do you write / have packages ? Anyways, I'll put this one in my own utility package :)

Comment: You're welcome, it was a fun thing to hack! I've start writing one quite recently, but there isn't a lot to it yet. There is some stuff related to my job, but also a function to force panel sizes and set multiple colour scales in one plot. It's on github under the same username /ggnomics.

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible with the CRAN package {ggh4x}. Funny fact, the geom for this package saw the light of the day on this SO post :) Thanks teunbrand!

```r
library(ggh4x)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
ggplot(pressure, aes(temperature, pressure)) + 
  geom_pointpath()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>