# How to offset arrow lengths in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a ggplot like this:

[image]

Dataset and code to produce the graph at the end.

I want to shorten the arrows, so they don't touch the points, very similar to this question:
[Arranging arrows between points nicely in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647988/arranging-arrows-between-points-nicely-in-ggplot2)

The code below is slightly modified from here, in an attempt to deal with the updates in ggplot2:
https://pastebin.com/0BRwUzpu

However, when I run my ggplot code I get the following error:

```
Error in geom_segment_plus(aes(x=...
  attempt to apply non-function
```

I'm not an expert at doing behind the scenes R code, and perhaps that shows, but it would be really great if someone could get this code to work.

(by the way, I think this feature would be a fantastic addition to ggplot)

#### Modified code

```
library(ggplot2)

geom_segment_plus <- function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity",
  position = "identity", arrow = NULL, lineend = "butt", na.rm = FALSE, ...) {

  GeomSegmentPlus$new(mapping = mapping, data = data, stat = stat,
    position = position, arrow = arrow, lineend = lineend, na.rm = na.rm, ...)
}


GeomSegmentPlus <- ggproto(ggplot2:::GeomRaster, expr={
  objname <- "segmentplus"

  draw <- function(., data, scales, coordinates, arrow = NULL,
    lineend = "butt", na.rm = FALSE, ...) {

    data <- remove_missing(data, na.rm = na.rm,
      c("x", "y", "xend", "yend", "linetype", "size", "shape","shorten.start","shorten.end","offset"),
      name = "geom_segment_plus")
    if (empty(data)) return(zeroGrob())

    if (is.linear(coordinates)) {
        data = coord_transform(coordinates, data, scales)
          for(i in 1:dim(data)[1] )
          {
                match = data$xend == data$x[i] & data$x == data$xend[i] & data$yend == data$y[i] & data$y == data$yend[i]
                #print("Match:")
                #print(sum(match))
                if( sum( match ) == 0 ) data$offset[i] <- 0
          }

          data$dx = data$xend - data$x
          data$dy = data$yend - data$y
          data$dist = sqrt( data$dx^2 + data$dy^2 )
          data$px = data$dx/data$dist
          data$py = data$dy/data$dist

          data$x = data$x + data$px * data$shorten.start
          data$y = data$y + data$py * data$shorten.start
          data$xend = data$xend - data$px * data$shorten.end
          data$yend = data$yend - data$py * data$shorten.end
          data$x = data$x - data$py * data$offset
          data$xend = data$xend - data$py * data$offset
          data$y = data$y + data$px * data$offset
          data$yend = data$yend + data$px * data$offset

      return(with(data,
        segmentsGrob(x, y, xend, yend, default.units="native",
        gp = gpar(col=alpha(colour, alpha), fill = alpha(colour, alpha),
          lwd=size * .pt, lty=linetype, lineend = lineend),
        arrow = arrow)
      ))
    }
                print("carrying on")

    data$group <- 1:nrow(data)
    starts <- subset(data, select = c(-xend, -yend))
    ends <- rename(subset(data, select = c(-x, -y)), c("xend" = "x", "yend" = "y"),
      warn_missing = FALSE)

    pieces <- rbind(starts, ends)
    pieces <- pieces[order(pieces$group),]

    GeomPath$draw_groups(pieces, scales, coordinates, arrow = arrow, ...)
  }


  default_stat <- function(.) StatIdentity
  required_aes <- c("x", "y", "xend", "yend")
  default_aes <- function(.) aes(colour="black", size=0.5, linetype=1, alpha = NA,shorten.start=0,shorten.end=0,offset=0)
  guide_geom <- function(.) "path"
})
```

Dataset:

```
structure(list(Treatment = c("Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Treatment", 
"Treatment", "Treatment", "Treatment", "Treatment", "Treatment", 
"Treatment", "Treatment"), Time = c("Post", "Post", "Post", "Post", 
"Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Post", "Post", "Post", "Pre", "Pre", 
"Pre", "Pre", "Pre"), Site = c("B", "A", "H", "P", "A", "G", 
"H", "P", "B", "G", "H", "B", "A", "G", "H", "P"), Type = c("PostControl", 
"PostControl", "PostControl", "PostControl", "PreControl", "PreControl", 
"PreControl", "PreControl", "PostTreatment", "PostTreatment", 
"PostTreatment", "PreTreatment", "PreTreatment", "PreTreatment", 
"PreTreatment", "PreTreatment"), MD1 = c(-1.232682838, 1.313007519, 
-0.165953812, -0.123767165, 0.940689029, 0.293944614, 0.940689029, 
0.940689029, -0.401351793, 0.867036009, 0.003610098, -1.214486723, 
0.940689029, -0.694974611, -1.192650691, -1.214486723), MD2 = c(-0.50627891, 
-0.3392641, 0.53072355, 0.53982618, 0.57810777, -1.23757431, 
0.57810777, 0.57810777, -1.60422721, -0.83598169, 0.02060607, 
0.92139307, 0.57810777, -0.76083124, 0.03778445, 0.92139307)), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Treatment = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Time = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Site = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), MD1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), MD2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector"))), class = "col_spec"))
```

Main graph code:

```
xmin <- signif(min(df$MD1))
xmax <- signif(max(df$MD1))
ymin <- signif(min(df$MD2)) 
ymax <- signif(max(df$MD2))

ggplot(df) +
  ggtitle("Soil")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=25, face="bold"))+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", size = 1))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),   axis.title=element_blank(),                              
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),  axis.ticks=element_blank())+
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=18), legend.justification = "top", legend.title=element_text(size=19))+

  geom_point(data=df,inherit.aes=FALSE, aes(x=MD1, y=MD2, shape=Type),size=9,  stroke=3)+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16, 15, 1, 0), name="Treatment")+
  annotate(geom = 'segment', y = Inf, yend = Inf, color = 'black', x = -Inf, xend = Inf, size = 3) +
  annotate(geom = 'segment', y = -Inf, yend = Inf, color = 'black', x = Inf, xend = Inf, size = 3)+
  annotate(geom = 'segment', y = -Inf, yend = Inf, color = 'black', x = -Inf, xend = -Inf, size = 3)+
  annotate(geom = 'segment', y = Inf, yend = Inf, color = 'black', x = -Inf, xend = -Inf, size = 3)+

  geom_segment(aes(x=MD1[df$Treatment=="Control"& df$Site=="A"&df$Time=="Pre"],  
                        y=MD2[df$Treatment=="Control"& df$Site=="A"&df$Time=="Pre"],
                        xend=MD1[df$Treatment=="Control"& df$Site=="A"&df$Time=="Post"], 
                        yend=MD2[df$Treatment=="Control"& df$Site=="A"&df$Time=="Post"]),
                        arrow=arrow(), size=2, color="black")+
  geom_segment(aes(x=MD1[df$Treatment=="Treatment"& df$Site=="G"&df$Time=="Pre"], y=MD2[df$Treatment=="Treatment"& df$Site=="G"&df$Time=="Pre"],
                   xend=MD1[df$Treatment=="Treatment"& df$Site=="G"&df$Time=="Post"], yend=MD2[df$Treatment=="Treatment"& df$Site=="G"&df$Time=="Post"]),
               arrow=arrow(),  size=2, color="blue")+
  geom_segment(aes(x=MD1[df$Treatment=="Treatment"& df$Site=="H"&df$Time=="Pre"], y=MD2[df$Treatment=="Treatment"& df$Site=="H"&df$Time=="Pre"],
                   xend=MD1[df$Treatment=="Treatment"& df$Site=="H"&df$Time=="Post"], yend=MD2[df$Treatment=="Treatment"& df$Site=="H"&df$Time=="Post"]),
               arrow=arrow(),  size=2, color="blue")+
  geom_segment(aes(x=MD1[df$Treatment=="Control"& df$Site=="H"&df$Time=="Pre"],  y=MD2[df$Treatment=="Control"& df$Site=="H"&df$Time=="Pre"],
                   xend=MD1[df$Treatment=="Control"& df$Site=="H"&df$Time=="Post"], yend=MD2[df$Treatment=="Control"& df$Site=="H"&df$Time=="Post"]),
               arrow=arrow(), size=2, color="black")+
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(ymin, ymax),xlim=c(xmin, xmax))
```

Graph code. To reproduce the error, after running the custom function above, replace

```
geom_segment(aes(x=MD1[df$Treatment=="Control"& df$Site=="A"&df$Time=="Pre"],  
                            y=MD2[df$Treatment=="Control"& df$Site=="A"&df$Time=="Pre"],
                            xend=MD1[df$Treatment=="Control"& df$Site=="A"&df$Time=="Post"], 
                            yend=MD2[df$Treatment=="Control"& df$Site=="A"&df$Time=="Post"]),
                            arrow=arrow(), size=2, color="black")+
```

with

```
  geom_segment_plus(aes(x=MD1[CBSoil.sum$Treatment=="Control"& CBSoil.sum$Site=="Flynns"&CBSoil.sum$Time=="Pre"],  
                   y=MD2[CBSoil.sum$Treatment=="Control"& CBSoil.sum$Site=="Flynns"&CBSoil.sum$Time=="Pre"],
                   xend=MD1[CBSoil.sum$Treatment=="Control"& CBSoil.sum$Site=="Flynns"&CBSoil.sum$Time=="Post"], 
                   yend=MD2[CBSoil.sum$Treatment=="Control"& CBSoil.sum$Site=="Flynns"&CBSoil.sum$Time=="Post"]),
                offset=0.01, shorten.start=0.03, shorten.end=0.03,
                               arrow=arrow(), size=2, color="black")+
```

Comment: Is there are reason why are your creating custom `geom_layer` for that? Also, please add your PCA values to reproduce your plot.

Comment: I don't want to have to use custom layers. There is no other way that I can find to add offsetted arrows easily. Datset and graph code added.