# How to show direction (heading) of obs in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

How can I show the direction (heading) of observations using ggplot2? Is there a way to adjust `shape=17`(triangle) so that it "points" to the next time observations?

**Example Code**

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), 
                  time = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
                  x = c(.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6),
                  y = c(.6, .25, .4, .33, .2, .51))


ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, color=factor(id))) + 
  geom_point(shape=17) + 
  # geom_line() +
  NULL
```

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify: you want each triangle to "point" to the next one along the x-axis?

Comment: @John Yes, so the obs show directions.

Comment: Where does the last one point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [`ggplot2::geom_segment`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_segment.html) after we reshape the data using 
`dplyr` and `tidyr::pivot_wider`:

```
dat <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), 
                  time = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
                  x = c(.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6),
                  y = c(.6, .25, .4, .33, .2, .51))
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
dat %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = time, values_from = c(x, y)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x_1, y=y_1, color=factor(id))) + 
  geom_segment(aes(xend = x_2, yend = y_2),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(.3,"cm"))) +
  labs(x="x", y="y", color="id")
```

[image: ggplot with arrows]

## Edit:

> but I just want the arrow pointing without lines.

I'm not sure how we should handle the second point for each id (since it has *not direction*) but if we want to omit them from the plot we can do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
dat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(id, time) %>% 
  mutate(x_2 = x + 0.0001 * (lead(x) - x),
         y_2 = y + 0.0001 * (lead(y) - y)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(x_2)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, color=factor(id))) + 
  geom_segment(aes(xend = x_2, yend = y_2),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(.3,"cm"))) +
  labs(x="x", y="y", color="id")
```

[image: no lines or dots]

Or if we want the arrows to point to the next measurement, independently of the color we can use the code below (now there is only the last point missing because of no direction):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
dat %>% 
  arrange(id, time) %>% 
  mutate(x_2 = x + 0.0001 * (lead(x) - x),
         y_2 = y + 0.0001 * (lead(y) - y)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(x_2)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, color=factor(id))) + 
  geom_segment(aes(xend = x_2, yend = y_2),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(.3,"cm"))) +
  labs(x="x", y="y", color="id")
```

**If we want to keep the 'last' measures** we could add them in another `geom_point` layer...

Comment: Thanks. This is a good suggestion, but I just want the arrow pointing without lines.

Comment: I just need a snap-shot in time (`t=1`) so I only need the next obs. Your arrow solution works, but wish I could remove the dot

Comment: Do you mean the smallish dot drawn in the 'corner' of the arrows? To get rid of that just replace the coefficient `0.01` with `0.0001` or something super small ;) I edited my example to include that improvement!

Comment: @Vedda Is this still not the answer you were looking for? We could adapt the arrow a bit if you want more customization

Comment: Thanks! Not exactly what I was looking for but close enough. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Combining ideas from *dario's answer*, [How to scale a 2D vector and keep direction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347328/how-to-scale-a-2d-vector-and-keep-direction) and [Arranging arrows between points nicely in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647988/arranging-arrows-between-points-nicely-in-ggplot2)

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = time, values_from = c(x, y)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(x_v = x_2 - x_1, y_v = y_2 - y_1) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars("x_v", "y_v"), 
            list(units =~ (. / sqrt((x_v)^2 + (y_v)^2))/1000)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x_1, y=y_1, colour = factor(id))) + 
  geom_segment(aes(xend = x_1 + x_v_units, yend = y_1 + y_v_units),
              show.legend = F,
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(.3,"cm"), type="closed", angle = 20)) +
  geom_point(data = (dat %>% filter(time == 2)), aes(x, y), shape=15, size=2) +
  labs(x="x", y="y", colour="id") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

***Data:***

```r
dat <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), 
                  time = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
                  x = c(.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6),
                  y = c(.6, .25, .4, .33, .2, .51))
```