# ggnetwork scale edge and node (vertex) size independently (different geoms different scales)

Tags: r, ggplot2

### Problem:

I want to use a different size scale for edges and nodes in a network created with the ggnetwork package. If you look at the image below you may think I already did that since they all have different sizes but in fact edge and node size are not scaled independently in this plot. They are both scaled by the `scale_size_area()` function towards the same maximum (30).  If I get larger nodes my edges will shrink. I guess my problem boils down to scaling the size of different geoms with different functions. So for example how can I scale the size of the nodes with `scale_size_area(max_size = 30)` and the size of the edges with `scale_size_continuous(range = c(1,6))`?

### Example code:

```
#load packages
library(network)
library(sna)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnetwork)

#create data
#data for edges
edge_df<-data.frame(group1=c("A","A","B"),
           group2=c("B","C","C"),
           connection_strength=c(1,2,3))

#data for nodes/vertexes
vertex_df<-data.frame(group=c("A","B","C"),
                      groupsize=c(2,3,4))

#create network
my_network<-network(edge_df[,1:2],directed = FALSE)

#add edge attribute (interaction strength) to network object
set.edge.attribute(my_network, "connection_strength", edge_df$connection_strength)

#add node/vertex info to network object with the special %v% operator
my_network %v% "groupsize" = vertex_df$groupsize 

#plot
ggplot(my_network, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend,color=vertex.names)) +
  #edge size depends on connection strength
  geom_edges(color = "black",aes(size=connection_strength/20)) +
  #node size depends on groupsize
  geom_nodes(aes(size=groupsize)) +
  #scale size area is good for nodesize but I want a different scaling for the edges
  scale_size_area(max_size = 30,guide=F)+
  scale_color_discrete(guide=F)+#remove colour legend
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-0.15,1.15))+#add some space to x-axis
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-0.15,1.15))+#add some space to y-axis
  theme_bw()#simple plot layout
```

### Example plot:

### [image: example network plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647794/using-multiple-size-scales-in-a-ggplot).

I'm not a ggplot2 expert, but as far I understand, dual-scaling (e.g. having two y-axes or two color scales) contradicts the grammar of graphics.

The [solution to the aforementioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14984350/635806) might work, but it's a hack.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using scale_edge_width, it allows you to constrain the edges to a range of values - there are a variety of flavors (continuous, manual, etc), so adding the below command would constrain the edges to a range of 0.4 up to 2.

scale_edge_width(range = c(0.4,2))