# Different fill color for negative values in circular barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, gradient, geom-col

I'm trying to figure out how to do this circular bar plot with blue color for the negative values (i.e. for Russia, Poland, Germany, and China) instead of purples/pinkish. I've been trying to change the colors and breaks, but I can't get it to break at zero.

[image]

Reproducible example:

```
uni_data <- structure(list(from = c("Argentina", "Canada", "China", "Germany", 
"Malawi", "Mexico", "Poland", "Russia", "South Africa", "United Republic of Tanzania", 
"United States", "Zambia"), to = c("Zimbabwe", "Zimbabwe", "Zimbabwe", 
"Zimbabwe", "Zimbabwe", "Zimbabwe", "Zimbabwe", "Zimbabwe", "Zimbabwe", 
"Zimbabwe", "Zimbabwe", "Zimbabwe"), fraction_mean = c(-1.16218764988057, 
0.556848791658583, -0.785724007068475, -0.668776616353553, 2.98715326478044, 
0.632802483886891, -0.952039672216194, -0.275904847337713, 1.91885749928563, 
2.18477200782915, -1.22917889731657, 4.4028142502411), d_long = c(0.124, 
0.2794, 0.2466, 0.0785, 2.8646, 0.202, 0.1153, 0.1238, 0.2247, 
1.6428, 0.1664, 2.3044), mean_exposure = c(0.219336124378027, 
0.964248264036473, -0.833368763174394, -0.520689933363188, 1.45247015618433, 
-1.53268987398912, -1.15713981781644, 0.791178790005572, 0.482041972598713, 
2.02018800214932, 1.40628459671399, 2.61998072810955)), row.names = c(1L, 
5L, 6L, 9L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 22L, 25L, 26L, 27L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code (from https://r-graph-gallery.com/web-circular-barplot-with-R-and-ggplot2.html):

```
plot_uni <- uni_data %>%
  group_by(from) %>%
  summarise(
    sum_length = fraction_mean,
    mean_exposure = mean_exposure,
    delta = d_long
  ) %>%
  mutate(mean_exposure = round(mean_exposure, digits = 0))

plt2 <- ggplot(plot_uni) +
  # Make custom panel grid
  # geom_hline(
  #   aes(yintercept = y), 
  #   data.frame(y = c(0:7) * 1),
  #   color = "lightgrey"
  #) + 
  # Add bars to represent the cumulative track lengths
  # str_wrap(region, 5) wraps the text so each line has at most 5 characters
  # (but it doesn't break long words!)
  geom_col(
    aes(
      x = reorder(str_wrap(from, 5), sum_length),
      y = sum_length,
      fill = delta
    ),
    position = "dodge2",
    show.legend = TRUE,
    alpha = .9
  ) +
  
  # Add dots to represent the mean gain
  geom_point(
    aes(
      x = reorder(str_wrap(from, 5),sum_length),
      y = mean_exposure
    ),
    size = 3,
    color = "gray12"
  ) +
  
  # Lollipop shaft for mean gain per region
  geom_segment(
    aes(
      x = reorder(str_wrap(from, 5), sum_length),
      y = 0,
      xend = reorder(str_wrap(from, 5), sum_length),
      yend = 6
    ),
    linetype = "dashed",
    color = "gray12"
  ) + 
  
  # Make it circular!
  coord_polar() + 
  
  labs(x=" ", y=" ")

plt2

plt3 <- plt2 +
  # Scale y axis so bars don't start in the center
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(-1, 6),
    expand = c(0, 0),
    breaks = c(0,2, 3, 4)
  ) + 
  # New fill and legend title for number of tracks per region
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    "Delta in mm of extreme precipitation (%)",
    colours = c("#F8B195","#F67280","#C06C84","#6C5B7B")
  ) +
  # Make the guide for the fill discrete
  guides(
    fill = guide_colorsteps(
      barwidth = 20, barheight = .5, title.position = "top", title.hjust = .5)
  ) +
  theme(
    # Remove axis ticks and text
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    # Use gray text for the region names
    axis.text.x = element_text(color = "gray12", size = 10),
    # Move the legend to the bottom
    legend.position = "bottom",
  )

plt3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea for this has been addressed before in multiple threads (e.g. [ggplot2 positive and negative values different color gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700938/ggplot2-positive-and-negative-values-different-color-gradient)). But here, we need to take a couple of extra steps to achieve that.

First, since your fill colors are based on column `delta` and you want to have a different color for bars that have negative y values (i.e. `sum_length`), we need to modify `delta` to reflect that. So I changed `delta` to be equal to `abs(d_long) * sign(sum_length)`.

Then, we can use the same idea from the link above, and define our colors for negative and positive values. We define our colors (`colours = c("#073763", "#0A75AD","white", "#F67280", "#6C5B7B")`), and then tell ggplot to use them for our desired range (`values=rescale(c(min(plot_uni$delta), 0-.Machine$double.eps, 0, 0+.Machine$double.eps, max(plot_uni$delta))))`. Basically we use shades of blue for anything from minimum of our `delta` to slightly less than 0, white for 0, and shades of pink and purple for positive values up to maximum of `delta`.

I have also extended the limits and the segment to show every data point, and adjusted the theme to make the plot look cleaner.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
```

```
uni_data %>%
  group_by(from) %>%
  summarise(sum_length = fraction_mean,
            mean_exposure = mean_exposure,
            delta = abs(d_long) * sign(sum_length)) %>%
  mutate(mean_exposure = round(mean_exposure, digits = 0)) -> plot_uni
```

```
ggplot(plot_uni) +
  geom_col(aes(x = reorder(str_wrap(from, 5), sum_length), 
               y = sum_length,
               fill = delta),
    position = "dodge2", show.legend = TRUE, alpha = .9) +
  geom_point(aes(x = reorder(str_wrap(from, 5),sum_length),
                 y = mean_exposure),
             size = 3, color = "gray12") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = reorder(str_wrap(from, 5), sum_length),
                   y = -3,
                   xend = reorder(str_wrap(from, 5), sum_length),
                   yend = 6),
               linetype = "dashed", color = "gray12") + 
  coord_polar() + 
  labs(x=" ", y=" ") +

  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-4, 6), expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn("Delta in mm of extreme precipitation (%)",
                       colours = c("#073763", "#0A75AD","white", "#F67280", "#6C5B7B"),
                       values=rescale(c(min(plot_uni$delta), 
                                                0-.Machine$double.eps, 
                                                0, 
                                                0+.Machine$double.eps, 
                                                max(plot_uni$delta)))) +
  guides(fill = guide_colorsteps(barwidth = 20, barheight = .5, 
                                 title.position = "top", title.hjust = .5)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "gray12", size = 10),
        line = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Amazing - thanks! But setting ```delta``` to ```abs(d_long)``` does not appear in the code, only ```delta = d_long * sign(sum_length)```. Should it be ```delta = abs(d_long) * sign(sum_length)```? I'm not sure I fully understand what ```abs``` and ```sign``` does.

Comment: @MoonS `abs` was a an afterthought to be safe. Basically, here I het the value to be used fro fill from `delta` and the sign of that value from `sum_length`. You can break these into multiple steps (mutate multiple columns, one for abs, one for sign, etc.) to understand them better.