# Same scale in legend for circular bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart, legend

Building on this post and code (with reproducible example) [Different fill color for negative values in circular barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77483451/different-fill-color-for-negative-values-in-circular-barplot/77483723?noredirect=1#comment136600367_77483723), I want to plot two of these figures together as a comparison, like this:

[image]

But to enable comparison, the legend scales of the "Delta" (i.e. 0-2.5 and 4-5.5) instead needs to be identical. Is there a way to control the range of the scale of the bottom color bar for these figures to be plotted on the same scale?

Comment: Yes, just set `limits = c(0, 5.5)` inside `scale_fill_gradientn`