# ggplot2: Independent Continuous Fill for Summary Row & Column

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using a strategy to plot summary (totals) rows in a heatmap using `geom_tile`, which involves creating extra rows in the `data_frame` for row and column totals:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)    

entitites = LETTERS[1:10]
# create some sample data
df_foo = bind_cols(
  data_frame(Group1 = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 100)),
  bind_rows(
    expand.grid(
      Left = entitites, Right = entitites,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    ),
    expand.grid(
      Left = entitites, Right = entitites,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  ),
  data_frame(Value = rpois(200, 15))
)

# create the summary row & column
df_foo_aug = bind_rows(
  df_foo,
  df_foo %>% 
    group_by(Left, Group1) %>% 
    summarize(
      Value = sum(Value),
      Right = "Total"
    ),
  df_foo %>% 
    group_by(Right, Group1) %>% 
    summarize(
      Value = sum(Value),
      Left = "Total"
    )
)

# create the plot
df_foo_aug %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Right, y = Left, fill = Value)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  facet_wrap(~ Group1) + 
  theme_bw()
```

This yields:

[image]

Obviously, the totals row/column need their own fill gradient, but it is not clear how (if) I can add a second continuous/gradient fill.

Any other way to achieve the same intended outcome would be acceptable as a solution to this question as well.

Comment: `object 'entitites' not found`

Comment: @Axeman Added the definition of `entities`.

Comment: A [stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129876/ggplot2-multiple-scales-legends-per-aesthetic-revisited) which might be of use to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that in `ggplot`, in principle, an aesthetic can only have one scale. So `fill` can only have one scale. However, there are some ways to avoid this, for example by using `color` for a second scale. Alternatively, you could mess around with grobs to get the job done, as per [shayaa's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116838/ggplot2-independent-continuous-fill-for-summary-row-column#comment65580843_39116838).

Here are some possible examples, using `geom_point` to display the totals:

```
base_plot <-  
  ggplot(df_foo_aug, aes(x = Right, y = Left)) + 
  geom_tile(data = filter(df_foo_aug, Right != 'Total', Left != 'Total'), 
            aes(fill = Value)) +
  coord_equal() +
  facet_wrap(~ Group1) + 
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(sort(unique(df_foo_aug$Left)))) +
  theme_classic() + theme(strip.background = element_blank())
```

A fairly standard approach:

```
base_plot +
  geom_point(data = filter(df_foo_aug, Right == 'Total' | Left == 'Total'), 
             aes(col = Value), size = 9.2, shape = 15) +
  scale_color_gradient('Total', low = 'black', high = 'red')
```

[image]

Using color scales with a wider perceptual range:

```
base_plot +
  geom_point(data = filter(df_foo_aug, Right == 'Total' | Left == 'Total'), 
            aes(col = Value), size = 9.2, shape = 15) +
  viridis::scale_fill_viridis(option = 'B') +
  viridis::scale_color_viridis('Total', option = 'D')
```

[image]

Also mapping `size` to the total `Value`:

```
base_plot +
  geom_point(data = filter(df_foo_aug, Right == 'Total' | Left == 'Total'), 
             aes(col = Value, size = Value)) +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 8, guide = 'none') +
  viridis::scale_fill_viridis(option = 'B') +
  viridis::scale_color_viridis('Total', option = 'D')
```

[image]

Personally, I quite like the last one.

One final improvement would be to move the y-axis up, for which I would recommend the [`cowplot` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/axis_position.html).

Comment: (+1) In principle, this is a fantastic answer -- I really appreciate it. However, there are details (which I did not think relevant to include) that make this solution not general enough for my problem. `coord_equal` is not possible to use in my case (asymmetric categories on x & y axes) and that makes the use of `shape = 15` ugly. If I avoid this problem by using default point shapes, I cannot fit the `geom_text` that gives the actual values within the point.

Comment: PS. I would much rather work within the framework you have set up, rather than mess about with grobs as in the answer @shayaa has linked to.

Comment: I cannot really help with details that I don't know. Asymmetry doesn't necessarily mean you cannot use `coord_equal`. You might be able create an extra column/row outside the current totals to fit the text.

Comment: Sure. I am adding those details - patience is a virtue. :-)