# Adding marginal totals to ggplot heatmap in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I want to add sum and row totals to my heatmap and struggling with already suggested ways to realize in other posts like here: [ggplot2: Independent Continuous Fill for Summary Row & Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116838/ggplot2-independent-continuous-fill-for-summary-row-column).

The problem with the above post is, that I do not understand the code where the totals (row, column) are created. Although it is marked as "# create the summary row & column" I don't get it.

So it would be great if...
 1. ...somebody could help me and show me a (simple) way to get there in reference to my posted code (below) and also 
 2. ...if the row- and column totals could have separate color scales.

I tried this...

```
# create sample
scen <- 1:32
ls <- rep(1:7, length(scen))
df <- data.frame(Landscape = ls, Scenario = scen)
df$SoP <- sample(seq(-0.070, 0.070, by = 0.01),replace=T, nrow(df))
df$Landscape_Name <- LETTERS[1:7]

# create heatmap
library(ggplot2)
df.diff <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Landscape_Name, y = Scenario)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = SoP)) +
  geom_text(size = 3, aes(label = round(SoP,2))) + #displays cell values
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "gold", #colors
                       mid = "white",
                       high = "grey",
                       midpoint = 0) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x=element_blank(), #no gridlines
        panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major.y=element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor.y=element_blank(),
        panel.background=element_rect(fill="white"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=0, hjust = 0.5,vjust=0.5, size = 8,face = NULL),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8,face = NULL),
        plot.title = element_text(size=10,face="bold")) +
  ggtitle("Treatment efficiency") + 
  theme(legend.title=element_text(face="bold", size=8)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(name="Landscape", position = "top") +
  scale_y_discrete(name="Scenario") +
  labs(fill="SoP")
print(df.diff)
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: what were the problems you faced with the method suggested in the post you referenced? also it's a bit tricky to help without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), can you add to you question the output of `dput(Delta)`?

Comment: I simplified the code (and the content of the question itself)  and added a reproducible sample for a better understanding. My challenge is to understand how to apply the suggested post (link) for my code. I dont think its complicated, but somehow I dont get it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's see if I can explain the answer in the post you referenced i.e., [ggplot2: Independent Continuous Fill for Summary Row & Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116838/ggplot2-independent-continuous-fill-for-summary-row-column)

First a couple of notes:

- On the `y` axis you're plotting a vector of numbers, which is considered a continuous scale, that's why the axis labels are disappearing when you run `scale_y_discrete`, while the plot is working fine, once we decide on adding a new value to the axis (i.e., `Total`) this will cause problems, which is why I think `Scenario` should be a character vector.
- Turning the column `Scenario` to string using `as.character` will mess up sorting the values, try for example running `sort(as.character(1:20))`, this can be avoided by using 2 digit numbers (01, 02, 03, .....), and that's what I did down there
- In the above mentioned answer the totals were binded with the original df, however I will use them as external data to make it easier to understand (or at least I think it's easier this way)

So here we go:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# pad numbers with zeros to get 2 digit numbers, this will be a string
scen <- sprintf('%02d', 1:32)
ls <- rep(1:7, length(scen))
df <- data.frame(Landscape = ls, Scenario = scen)
df$SoP <- sample(seq(-0.070, 0.070, by = 0.01),replace=T, nrow(df))
df$Landscape_Name <- LETTERS[1:7]

# create the main plot, and take a look at it
df.diff <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Landscape_Name, y = Scenario)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = SoP)) +
  geom_text(size = 3, aes(label = round(SoP,2))) + #displays cell values
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "gold", #colors
                       mid = "white",
                       high = "grey",
                       midpoint = 0) 

df.diff
```

Now we want the data which allows us to add an extra category to `Landscape_Name` and an extra category to `Scenario`, such that:

- The category added to `Landscape_Name` (the horizontal sums) is the sum of all `SoP` for each `Scenario`, and
- The category added to `Scenario` (the vertical sums) is the sum of all `SoP` for each `Landscape_Name`

Basically we need `group_by` and `sum`

```
h_total <- df %>% 
  group_by(Scenario) %>% 
  summarise(SoP = sum(SoP)) %>% 
  mutate(Landscape_Name = 'Total')


v_total <- df %>% 
  group_by(Landscape_Name) %>% 
  summarise(SoP = sum(SoP)) %>% 
  mutate(Scenario = 'Total')
```

Now we can add the grouped data to the original plot, with `geom_point`, because we used the same column names in the new data, the `x` and `y` aesthetics will be inherited from the original plot, and to have a different color scheme as the original plot we use `color` (not `fill`), which works fine with the chosen shape.

If you want the cell values for the totals as well, you have to add layers for those too

```
p <- df.diff + 
  geom_point(data = h_total, 
             aes(color = SoP), 
             size = 10, 
             shape = 19) +
  geom_point(data = v_total, 
             aes(color = SoP), 
             size = 10, 
             shape = 19) +
  scale_color_gradient2(low = "red", #colors
                        mid = "white",
                        high = "grey",
                        midpoint = 0) +
  geom_text(data = h_total, size = 3, aes(label = round(SoP,2))) +
  geom_text(data = v_total, size = 3, aes(label = round(SoP,2)))

p
```

Finally add the theme customisations, title, and axis and legend labels

```
p  +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x=element_blank(), #no gridlines
        panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major.y=element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor.y=element_blank(),
        panel.background=element_rect(fill="white"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=0, hjust = 0.5,vjust=0.5, size = 8,face = NULL),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8,face = NULL),
        plot.title = element_text(size=10,face="bold"),
        legend.title=element_text(face="bold", size=8))  + 
  scale_x_discrete(name="Landscape", position = "top") +
  scale_y_discrete(name="Scenario", 
                  # if you want the total to be at the bottom instead of at the top, 
                  # you can set the limits of y  with the reversed order of the categories 
                  limits = rev(c(unique(as.character(df$Scenario)), 'Total'))) + 
  # you can here change the y/x ratio 
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.4) +
  labs(fill="SoP", color ="SoP Total") +
  ggtitle("Treatment efficiency")
```

I finally saved the plot with `ggsave(' PATH/TO/plot.jpeg', width =20, height = 40, units = 'cm')`

and this was the output

[image]

Comment: Great approach! Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Glad to help! Please accept my answer if it solved your problem, I would really appreciate that, as well as others, since that could help those who might face similar problems.

Comment: One follow up question: Is it possible to set up separate colors for the x- and y-axis of the totals? 
Currently, the color mode represents min and max values of both totals, but I would have to separate this so that only x-axis values and only y-axis values are addressed.
Thanks a lot for your help, again!

Comment: This is really great (thank you), but it failed for me when you need to re-order the heatmap rows and columns. Or in other words as the rows and columns are ordered alphabetically it all works. But if the landscape name was e.g. ...S, T, U... then Total would appear in the middle of the heat map. I couldn't figure this out myself using factor() for ordering?

Comment: I found a way to do this. Not with factors but with ordering the x  & y axis labels using `scale_x_discrete(limits = c(my_var_names, "Total"), position = "top")` etc..
Inspiration came from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65856117/ggplot2-how-to-add-total-to-a-heatmap?rq=1