# ggplot2-How to add total to a heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am trying to create a genus level heatmap for microbial community identified in my samples.

Problem

I wanted to add sum and row totals to my heatmap (the total abundance of all genes for each samples and the total abundance of each genes for all samples). However, I struggled to work with the code so that I can add the total values without changing my data and my previous codes.

My attempted workaround :

I tried to use the following codes to plot my heatmap. However, the resulting plot was weird.

My data frame:

```
Gene     Sample1    Sample2   Sample3    Sample4  Sample5   Total
 A        0.0186     1.578     3.478     0.0045    0.569    5.648
 B        0.0009     0.125     1.254     5.890     1.590    8.8599
 C        2.567      0.897     0.0026    1.285     2.648    7.3996
 D        10.421     0.743     0.0152    0.479     6.489    18.1472
...        ...        ...       ...      ...      ...       ...
Total     34.49      11.1      11.72     18.19     24.52    100
```

My transformed data:

```
   Gene    Sample   Abundance      
A          1          0.0186        
B          1          0.0009        
C          1          2.567      
D          1          10.421              
...       ...         ...
```

My code:

```
p1 <- ggplot(data=heatmap, 
       mapping=aes(x= Sample, y= Gene, fill= Abundance)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  facet_grid (~ Sample, scales = "free", space = "free") +
  scale_fill_distiller(name = "Relative Abundance (%)", palette = "RdYlGn") + 
  theme(text = element_text(size=12), 
        axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 11, colour = "black"), 
        strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0), 
        legend.direction = "horizontal", 
        legend.position = "bottom")
+ scale_x_discrete(position = "top") 

p2 <- p1 + geom_point(data = heatmap, aes(color = Abundance),size = 10, shape = 19) 
         + scale_color_gradient2(low = "red", mid = "white",high = "grey", midpoint = 0) 
         + geom_text(data = heatmap, size = 3, aes(label = round(Abundance,2)))
p2
```

Result:

[image]

I appreciate any suggestions on how I could change the plot for better visualizing and any suggestions on how to add the horizontal and vertical sum.

Comment: Hm. On my machine your code works fine. I get a nice heatmap with labels and a row and a column with totals.

Comment: @stefan Did you get the similar plot that I got?

Comment: Nop. After reshaping your data to long using `tidy::pivot_longer` and running your code I get this plot https://i.imgur.com/O72GAxp.png

Comment: @stefan That looks so good. would you mind providing the codes so that I can better understand?

Comment: @stefan But I actually wanted to separate the total sums so they won't affect the scale. Like this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Xbd.jpg. But I didn't know how to manipulate the code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. In my opinion there is no need to make use of `facet_grid`. Instead you could filter the data used for the `geom_tile` and `geom_point` layer.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

heatmap <- read.table(text = "Gene     Sample1    Sample2   Sample3    Sample4  Sample5   Total
 A        0.0186     1.578     3.478     0.0045    0.569    5.648
 B        0.0009     0.125     1.254     5.890     1.590    8.8599
 C        2.567      0.897     0.0026    1.285     2.648    7.3996
 D        10.421     0.743     0.0152    0.479     6.489    18.1472
Total     34.49      11.1      11.72     18.19     24.52    100", header = TRUE)

heatmap <- heatmap %>%
  pivot_longer(-Gene, names_to = "Sample", values_to = "Abundance")

ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Sample, y = Gene)) +
  geom_tile(data = filter(heatmap, Gene != "Total", Sample != "Total"), aes(fill = Abundance)) +
  geom_point(data = filter(heatmap, Gene == "Total" | Sample == "Total"), aes(color = Abundance), size = 10, shape = 19) +
  geom_text(data = heatmap, aes(label = round(Abundance, 2)), size = 3) + 
  scale_color_gradient2(low = "red", mid = "white", high = "grey", midpoint = 0) +
  scale_fill_distiller(name = "Relative Abundance (%)", palette = "RdYlGn") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = unique(heatmap$Sample), position = "top") +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(unique(heatmap$Gene))) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    text = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 11, colour = "black"),
    strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0),
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    legend.position = "bottom",
    panel.grid.major = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]