# Plot data over background image with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot some data over a background image.  The problem is that both layers end up using the same scale.  This is unfortunately problematic.

An example.

I want to plot some data over this [image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39251/image.jpg).

[image: sample image]

Right.  So I plot it in ggplot like so.

```
img <- readJPEG("image.jpg")
image <- apply(img, 1:2, function(v) rgb(v[1], v[2], v[3]))
image <- melt(image)
ggplot(image, aes(row, -column, fill=fill)) + geom_tile() + scale_fill_identity()
```

And it works well.  So, let's add some data on top.

```
df <- data.frame(x=sample(1:64, 1000, replace=T), 
  y=sample(1:64, 1000, replace=T))
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + stat_bin2d()
```

Plotting the sample data, I get [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39251/data.png).
[image]

So I just want this data plot layered over the gradient image.

```
ggplot(image, aes(row, -column, fill=fill)) + geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_identity() + geom_point(data=df2, aes(x=x, y=-y))
```

But it ends up like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39251/ugly.png)

[image]

Trying to specify a second fill scale throws an error.  I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752709/using-two-scale-colour-gradients-on-one-ggplot) says it can't be done, but I'm hoping that there is a workaround or something I'm overlooking.

Comment: [This](http://kohske.wordpress.com/2010/12/26/use-image-for-background-in-ggplot2/) post is old and would need some updating for the newer versions of ggplot, but it might at least suggest a way out.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this, (or alternatively annotation_raster)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(jpeg)
library(grid)

img <- readJPEG("image.jpg")

df <- data.frame(x=sample(1:64, 1000, replace=T), 
                 y=sample(1:64, 1000, replace=T))

ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  annotation_custom(rasterGrob(img, width=unit(1,"npc"), height=unit(1,"npc")), 
                    -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf) +
  stat_bin2d() +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Note that this does not work with `coord_polar`, but one can find a solution for that case at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496000/trying-to-add-an-image-to-a-polar-plot-gives-error-annotation-custom-only-work.