# Trying to add an image to a polar plot gives "Error: annotation_custom only works with Cartesian coordinates"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've tried to follow the [answer's given already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917049/inserting-an-image-to-ggplot2) for adding images to plots, but they do not work when using `coord_polar()`

```
# install.packages("RCurl", dependencies = TRUE)
library(RCurl)
myurl <- "http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/micronations/images/5/50/German_flag.png"

# install.packages("png", dependencies = TRUE)
library(png)
img <-  readPNG(getURLContent(myurl))

# install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)

ger <- grid::rasterGrob(img, interpolate=TRUE)

## works, adds the image to the plot
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y= cyl)) + geom_line() + annotation_custom(ger, 10, 15, 5)

## doesn't work
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y= cyl)) + geom_line() + annotation_custom(ger) + coord_polar()
> Error: annotation_custom only works with Cartesian coordinates
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to position the flag image within the center of the polar plot, and another image along the y-axis.

Is there anyway to add the image? It can be as-is, no transformation required.

I'm using `ggplot2` version 2.0

Comment: It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you make a minimal _reproducible_ example to go along with your question (what is `ex`?).

Comment: Typo sorry, ex is mtcars

Comment: Do you want the images to be transformed from cartesian to polar coordinates as well? Or do you want the image, as-is, to be added to the top of the polar plot? If the latter, the `cowplot` package might do what you need.

Comment: The image to be as-is. I'll add to question, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gregor's suggestion for using the `cowplot` library has got me there.

Following the [introduction to cowplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html) you can use the `draw_grob` function to overlay images as you like.  It takes a bit of tweaking as the position changes depending on the dimensions of the plot, but its possible.

Example:

```
# install.packages("RCurl", dependencies = TRUE)
library(RCurl)
myurl <- "http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/micronations/images/5/50/German_flag.png"

# install.packages("png", dependencies = TRUE)
library(png)
img <-  readPNG(getURLContent(myurl))

# install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)

ger <- grid::rasterGrob(img, interpolate=TRUE)

g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y= cyl)) + geom_line() + coord_polar()

# install.packages("cowplot", dependencies = TRUE)
library(cowplot)
h <- ggdraw(g)
## tweak this to fit your plot
h + draw_grob(ger, 0.4, 0.48, 0.07, 0.07)
```

[image]

Comment: Draw_grob does nothing more than calling annotation_custom: > draw_grob
function (grob, x = 0, y = 0, width = 1, height = 1) 
{
    annotation_custom(grid::grobTree(grob), xmin = x, xmax = x + 
        width, ymin = y, ymax = y + height)
}
<environment: namespace:cowplot>
it also fails when plotting on a ggmap