# Plot picture in background with ggplot and plotly in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, plotly

I am hoping to plot a picture behind a bar chart. I have been following this question ([Plot data over background image with ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409935/plot-data-over-background-image-with-ggplot)) to some success (troubling doing with a bar chart).

But I have been trying to plot my `ggplot` in `plotly` but get the error code:

> ```
> Warning message:
> In geom2trace.default(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]], dots[[3L]][[1L]]) :
>   geom_GeomCustomAnn() has yet to be implemented in plotly.
> ```

It seems as if you cannot use this logic within plotly. Is there any way around this? Examples are appreciated.

**Example of my problem:**

```
img <- readJPEG("~/Documents/DWat.jpeg")

dw <- ggplot(ThirdDown, aes(Receiver, Targets)) + geom_bar(aes(text=Rec), stat="identity", fill="orange") +
  annotation_custom(rasterGrob(img, width=unit(1,"npc"), height=unit(1,"npc")), 
                   -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf) + stat_bin2d() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) 
dw
ggplotly(dw, hoverinfo="text+x+y")
```

Comment: Could you give a reproducible example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Hack-R check out the example above. Sorry its not the most reproducible but hopefully it will show what I'm trying to do