# ggplot2: plotting two size aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2

From what I can find on stackoverflow, (such as [this answer to using two scale colour gradients on one ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11752870/1664978)) this may not (yet) be possible with `ggplot2`.

I want to create a bubbleplot with two size aesthetics, one always larger than the other. The idea is to show the proportion as well as the absolute values. Now I could colour the points by the proportion but I prefer multi-bubbles. In Excel this is relatively simple.[image: Excel multiple aesethetic example on mtcars] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5LsF.png) Is there a way to replicate this in `ggplot2` (or base)?

Comment: can you please provide the data so that this is a reproducible example?

Comment: Sorry, it's `mtcars` with `mpg` on the x-axis, `wt` on the y-axis. The sizes are `hp/2` (black) and `disp` (white).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an option. Mapping `size` in two `geom_point` layers should work. It's a bit of a pain getting the sizes right for bubblecharts in ggplot though.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point(aes(size = disp), shape = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(size = hp/(2*disp))) + scale_size_continuous(range = c(15,30))
```

To get it looking most like your exapmle, add `theme_bw()`:

```
P <- p + theme_bw()
```

The `scale_size_continuous()` is where you have to just fiddle around till you're happy - at least in my experience. If someone has a better idea there I'd love to hear it.
[image]

Comment: Argh, I'd forgotten to enclose `size = ` with `aes()`! Thank you!

Comment: How do I implement that @agstudy? I've tried `p + theme(theme_bw())`

Comment: @flodel - sure, for plotting questions I usually try to restrict discussion down the very basics of the concept - hopefully it is less confusing. But `theme_bw` no doubt gets clost to the OP's original plot

Comment: and how can we label both variables??